# How to prevent back button after logging out of the website on php? I want it to redirect to the home page after logout

Tags: php, session

This is the logout code. But after logging out it allows me to go back to the previous pages but doesn't show any value since the sessions are destroyed instead it shows the error message saying value is not set.

```
    <?php

            session_start();
            session_destroy();    /* I have destroyed the sessions */
            header('location:Login.php')
    ?>
```

Comment: used `session_start` in index or previous page ?

Comment: How about performing the logout via AJAX and then redirect via `window.href` or something similar?

Comment: Yes. I have used session_start in all the pages. @TarangP

Comment: @TobiasF. I don't know how to use AJAX. I am newbie to AJAX. Could you help me with that?

Comment: In all pages check for login, if the user is not logged in, redirect to login page. When you press back after logout, it knows you are logged out and redirect again to `login.php`

Comment: @ata I have done that. But same problem.

Comment: You can share complete code so we can see it and help.